# Laravel Websockets - error:failed: Error in connection establishment:net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: laravel, websocket, phpwebsocket

I´ve been losing days on this one, read a lot of other questions but i can´t simply put this to work and don´t know where is my problem, so i was hopping someone could point me in the right direction. So below is the code i´m using to TRY! to implement websockets:(also i´m just using the pusher driver, not the account!)

**broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6002,
                'scheme' => 'https',
            ],
        ],
```

**websockets.php**

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => false,
        ],
    ],
...

'ssl' => [

        'local_cert' => 'certs/myDomain.cert',
         // i have created a certs 
         //folder in my public_html and downloaded the cert from my 
         //remote server

        'local_pk' => 'certs/myDomain.key', 
         // i have created a certs 
         //folder in my public_html and downloaded the key from my 
         //remote server

        'passphrase' => null // i don´t know the pass
    ],
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myKey',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wssPort: 6002,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

- If i go to the terminal and **php artisan websockets:serve
  --port=6002** the server starts and does not gives any error
- My website is HTTPS, and i don´t know how to implement reverse proxy
  like the docs say because i´m using apache and not nginx, and my
  panel is a mess to edit the files...and with ssl it should work right?

  Why does it say **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH** i don´t know what to do more

Thanks for your time, regards.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up using the reverserproxy solution that the docs talk about, i **DID NOT** find a solution using ssl but i´m pretty sure it has to do with my certificate and my provider...turns out that the reverseproxy solution is much more simpler, so to everyone out there struggling with the same issue i recomend doing this:

Go to your remote server panel(i have the CWP7) and open up your yourDomain.conf and inside put:

```
   ProxyPass/app/yourLaravelApp ws://yourDomain.com:theWebsocketPort/app/ginkgo 
   ProxyPass/app/yourLaravelApp ws://yourDomain.com:theWebsocketPort/app/ginkgo
```

That file that you have to edit is related of course with your webserver configuration, in my case i had myDomanin.ssl.conf and myDomain.conf, if you have the same, you **HAVE TO PUT THE CODE ABOVE IN BOTH FILES**, and that´s it!, enjoy.